# Get and update column of all rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a game and I want a script to run every minute (with the help of cron job, I guess).

So the script that I want to run takes the maximum HP of a character (from a column in a database table), calculates to get 10% of that value and then add those 10% to the characters current hp (which is another column in the table). I then want to iterate this over all rows in the database table.

E.g. consider the following table:

```
charname      current_hp      max_hp
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
player1               20          30
player2               15          64
player3               38          38
```

After the script has been run, I want the table to look like this:

```
charname      current_hp      max_hp
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
player1               23          30
player2               21          64
player3               38          38
```

So, I know how I technically could implement this, e.g.

```
$characters = $db->getCharacterList();

foreach ($characters as $character) {
    $maxHp = $character['max_hp'];
    $curHp = $character['current_hp'];
    $hpToAdd = $maxHp / 10;

    if (($curHp + $hpToAdd) >= $maxHp) {
        $db->update('characters', $character['id'], array(
            'current_hp' => $maxHp
        ));
    } else {
        $db->update('characters', $character['id'], array(
            'current_hp' => ($curHp + $hpToAdd)
        ));
    }
}
```

My only question is: Is the solution posted above an efficient way to implement this? Will this work on a table with, say, 10 000 rows, or will it take too long?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the following SQL statement does do the calcluations for you: `update characters set current_hp = max(current_hp + max_hp/10);`

Comment: How did player2's go from 15 to 19?  10% of 64 is 6.4, so one would imagine 15 becomes 21, or maybe even 22.

Comment: @eggyal Yeah, that was just me being sloppy... lol, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a SQL database? If you have 10,000 rows, your solution will hit the database 10,000 times. A SQL statement like this will only make one database hit:

```
UPDATE characters
SET current_hp = LEAST(max_hp, current_hp + (max_hp / 10))
```

The database will still have to do the I/O necessary to update all 10,000 rows, but it will happen more efficiently than thousands of individual queries.

Answer (score 0):

In One SQL statement will do all your requirements for more performance remove any indexes on this table to keep it fast

```
UPDATE test
SET current_hp= CASE
WHEN ((max_hp/10)+current_hp) >=max_hp THEN max_hp
ELSE  ((max_hp/10)+current_hp)
END
```